# Overriding Sub to check if value is numeric

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a problem with two user input controls, TextInput and NumericInput. TextInput accepts all characters, whereas NumericInput only accepts numeric inputs.

I'm aware that for my NumericInput Add Sub I will probably have to create a boolean to check if the input value is a number or not and then create an If statement using the boolean, however, I'm not sure how to go about this.

This is the code that I was able to come up with.

**For my TextInput code I currently have the following:**

```
 Dim value As String 'current value'

     Public Class TextInput
         Public Overridable Sub Add(c As Char)
             If value.length = 0 Then
                 value = Char.toString(c)
             Else
                 value+=c
             End If
         End Sub

         Public Function GetValue() As String
             Return value
          End Function
     End Class
```

**For my NumericInput code I currently have the following:**

```
     Public Class NumericInput
         Inherits TextInput

         Dim numericCheck As Boolean

         Public Overrides Sub Add(c As Char)
             If Not value.length = 0 Then
                 numericCheck = isNumeric(value)
             End If

             If numericCheck = True Then
                 value+=c
             End If
         End Sub
     End Class
```

**Output code is as follows:**

```
Public Sub Main()
        Dim input As TextInput = New NumericInput()
        input.Add(CChar("1"))
        input.Add(CChar("a"))
        input.Add(CChar("0"))
        Console.WriteLine(input.GetValue())
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the variable value should be encapsulated in TextInput class. You can declare it as protected so derived classes can access it. The value variable must have initial value otherwise value.Length raises an exception because it's null (Nothing).

Secondly, you can use IsNumeric function to check if a character is a number. Then call the base method of Add if it's a number.

```
Public Class TextInput
    Protected value As String = "" 'current value'
    Public Overridable Sub Add(c As Char)
        If value.Length = 0 Then
            value = Char.toString(c)
        Else
            value += c
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GetValue() As String
        Return value
    End Function
End Class

Public Class NumericInput
    Inherits TextInput

    Public Overrides Sub Add(c As Char)
        If IsNumeric(c) Then
            MyBase.Add(c)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```